# How to upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.4.3

Tags: grails

I am trying to upgrade from `2.2.4` to `2.4.3`

What is the best way to do this? I've made the following changes to my `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
plugins {
    runtime ':hibernate4:4.3.5.2'
    runtime ':jquery:1.11.0.2'
    runtime ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    //runtime ":resources:1.2"
    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.2.0.2'
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
    compile ":rabbitmq:1.0.0"
    compile (":events-push:1.0.M7") {
        excludes "resources"
    }
    compile ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"
    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
    build ':tomcat:7.0.52.1'
    runtime ':database-migration:1.4.0'
    compile ':cache:1.1.3'
    compile ":pretty-time:0.3"
    compile ":tagcloud:0.3"
    compile ':asset-pipeline:1.8.3'
}
```

After making the changes what command do I need to run? Are there changes I need to make now that since `resources` plugin is replaced with `asset-pipeline`

I've also changed `app.grails.version=2.2.4` in `application.properties` to `2.4.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we can't actually see any of the *changes* you've made.

> Are there changes I need to make now that since resources plugin is replaced with asset-pipeline

You can continue using the resources plugin in Grails 2.4.3, but if you want to migrate to the asset-pipeline, I'd advise you to do that after you have your app running stably on Grails 2.4.3.

> After making the changes what command do I need to run

`grails test-app` to automatically test if your app is still working. If you don't have any tests, run `grails run-app` and manually test it.

Comment: ok, I'm getting lot of errors when running the app with 2.4.3. I'll open a new question for those. Is it fine if I change `application.properties` manually?

Comment: @birdy you can either update the version manually or run the `set-grails-version` command.